# Is there a way to have Eclipse automatically create definitions for variables while I am writing code?

Tags: c, eclipse, plugins

Is there a way to have Eclipse automatically create definitions for variables while I am writing C code?

Often when writing code, I determine a new variable is required but it becomes tedious to stop and create definitions, declarations for these new variables. It would be useful to automate this so, I am wondering if Eclipse already supports something like this or would a dedicated plug-in be more appropriate? Ideally, I would like the variable declaration to be placed in a .h file of the same name as the current .c file.

Comment: Wait, how regularly are you putting variable declarations in *header* files?

Comment: ... most variables should not need a declaration in any header file, only in the current function.

Comment: To be clear, I am not declaring storage in a header file. Coding standards dictate certain variables definitions go into separate .c file and so need a variable declaration in a standalone header file in order to use them in the actual (functional) .c file.